# Why doesn't the hidden state of a neuron network provide better dimension reduction result than original input?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I just read a great post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63152/what-does-the-hidden-layer-in-a-neural-network-compute). I am curious about content of "An example with images" in that post. If the hidden states mean a lot of features of the original picture and getting closer to final result, using dimension reduction on hidden states should provide better result than the original raw pixels, I think.

Hence, I tried it on mnist digits with 2 hidden layers of 256 unit NN, using T-SNE for dimension reduction; the result is far from ideal. From left to right, top to bot, they are raw pixels, second hidden layer and final prediction. Can anyone explain that?

[image]

Comment: How good is your network at performing the task?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, Thanks for your replay. The accuracy is around 94.x%, which is able to distinguish most of digits. Would that be a reason to cause bad performance on dimension reduction?